# Smarty false is true?

Tags: smarty

I have a function for smarty:

```
function smarty_function_false_() {
    return false;
}
```

then if I do:

```
{if false_} false YES?? {else} false no {/if} <br>
{if not false_} not false yes {else} not false NO??? {/if}
```

And it evals to:

```
false YES??
not false NO???
```

I'm new to smarty, why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Smarty expression `{if false_}` does not evaluate any functions. It is equivalent to `{if 'false_'}`, which is in turn just the same as the PHP expression `if ( 'false_' )`. (Incidentally, `if ( false_ )` in PHP also means the same thing, unless you have run `define('false_', ...)`.)

Under PHP's "type juggling" rules, a string interpreted as a boolean is `true` as long as it is not the empty string (`''`). So `{if false_}` is equivalent to `{if true}`.

A [Smarty "template function"](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) is designed only to be called on its own, and return something to output to the template, e.g. `{false_}`.

The easiest way to have a callback that you can check inside an `{if}` condition is to define a ["modifier"](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl) rather than a "function". Although a modifier will always be given at least one parameter, it can simply be ignored, so you could have the following:

```
function smarty_modifier_false_($whatever) {
    return false;
}
```

And then in Smarty just pass any old string as the left of the modifier:

```
{if ''|false_} false_ is true!? {else} false_ is false. How reassuring. {/if}
```

Alternative approaches:

- Set the Security settings in your template such that you can write `{if false_()}`, because `false_` is a PHP function allowed directly in templates. (See [documentation on `{if}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl) where it links to [the details of Security](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security).)
- Register a [block function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.block.functions.tpl). These are a little trickier to write, but would allow you to have your own custom if replacement, e.g. `{if_false_} This text never appears {/if_false_}`.

Comment: I think it's actually easier to define a plain function (i.e., `false_` instead of `smarty_modifier_false_`, then register it and use it).

Comment: Oh :/ So is there any way to have `{if testSomething}` format? Or what is the nicest possible format for bool checks? Because `{if ''|userLoggedIn}` seems weird.

Comment: @raina77ow Am I misunderstanding you, or are you misunderstanding me? Registering it as a Smarty function is what the OP tried, and it doesn't work, because that's not how the `{if}` tag is defined.

Comment: @raina77ow I don't understand; whatever you call it, you still need to register it as a modifier, not a template function, or it will not be usable in the desired way.

Comment: Actually, you've just added that to your answer as an alternative approach #1. )

Comment: @psychobrm As I wrote in my answer, I think the easiest is to use a modifier, even if it has to be a slightly ugly one which doesn't really take any parameters. I've added a couple of other alternatives to my answer now, too.

Comment: @raina77ow Ah, right, that's what you were getting at! It was the word "register" that put me off, as that's usually used for registering a plugin of one sort or another, whereas in this case you're just whitelisting it under security settings.

Comment: @IMSoP well, that's really weird. Are those alternatives valid? -> `{if $checkValue}` or `{if getBool|eq_true}` (if eq_true was modifier)?

Comment: @psychobrm `{if $checkValue}` will evaluate the variable as a boolean, just like `if ( $checkValue )` would in PHP. `{if getBool|eq_true}` would just be the same as `{if 'getBool'|eq_true}` - `eq_true` is being evaluated as a modifier, but there's nothing to tell Smarty that `getBool` should be anything clever.